# .htaccess rule for compressing files with custom extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-deflate

I have the following `.htaccess` file copied directly from [html5boilerplate.com](http://html5boilerplate.com/):

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
          SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
          RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                application/javascript \
                                application/json \
                                application/rss+xml \
                                application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                application/x-font-ttf \
                                application/xhtml+xml \
                                application/xml \
                                font/opentype \
                                image/svg+xml \
                                image/x-icon \
                                text/css \
                                text/html \
                                text/plain \
                                text/x-component \
                                text/xml
</IfModule>
```

[YSlow](http://yslow.org/) shows only one file that isn't compressed and it's filename is `testing.cache` and it's content is a mix of html and css. I renamed the file to `testing.html` and the file got compressed just fine. I expected that the `testing.cache` file will get compressed too since it falls into the `text/html` group (this is a file I'm loading via ajax on page load). So, am wondering if I can something like:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(cache)$">
    someDirectiveToCache .cache file
</FilesMatch>
```

I've looked at [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) for any matching directive but to no luck. Sure I could leave it as `testing.html` but am wondering how it could be done for `testing.cache`. Also, I presumed the `FilesMatch` can be used within the `<IfModule mod_deflate.c>` module, since it can be (tested and using it) used inside the `<IfModule mod_expires.c>` like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(cache)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hour"
</FilesMatch>
```

My Apache version (if important) is: **2.2.15**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get this working, quite easy in the end actually. I went through all the documentation to find the `AddOutputFilter` directive which is plain simple and actually works with extensions.

The [AddOutputFilter directive syntax](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html) as stated in the docs for version 2.2 is:

```
AddOutputFilter filter[;filter...] extension [extension] ...
```

In my example after the `AddOutputFilterByType` directive I added:

```
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE cache
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.